# How to get minimum positive value and closest negative value to 0 using case_when in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to do the following:

Group the dataframe by 'id'

When all 'difft' is positive, return the 'animal' associated with the smallest positive value to 'myfilter'

When any of 'difft' is negative, return the 'animal' associated with the negative value closest to 0 to 'myfilter'

The following code does not seem to work:

```
tibble(
          id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
          animal = c("dog", "snake", "cat", "monkey", "fox", "mouse"),
          difft = c(-4, -33, 30, 9, 33, 1)
) %>%
          group_by(id) %>%
        
          mutate(myfilter = case_when(
                    all(difft > 0) ~ as.character(animal[difft == min(difft)]), #when all positive, get smallest positive
                    !all(difft > 0) ~ as.character(animal[difft == (min(abs(difft[difft <0]))*-1)]) #when any numbers neg, get smallest neg
          )) %>%
select(id, myfilter)
```

I would like the result to appear as follows:

```
id    myfilter
1    dog
1    dog
1    dog
2    mouse
2    mouse
2    mouse
```

Independently, the logic in each line of case_when will work when placed within the context of 'summarize', but for some reason I cannot get case_when to see both possible scenarios.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution which breaks this down into a few more steps:

Create a function that returns the highest negative value, or NA if no negative values:

```r
# function to return highest negative value
highest_negative <- function(x) {
  all_neg <- x[x <0]
  if (length(all_neg) > 0) {
    return(min(abs(all_neg))*-1)
  } else {
    return(NA_real_)
  }
}
```

then create columns that check (i) if all values positive or not, (ii) which value matches based on your criteria, (iii) selects the relevant animal.

```r
# select
tibble(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
  animal = c("dog", "snake", "cat", "monkey", "fox", "mouse"),
  difft = c(-4, -33, 30, 9, 33, 1)
) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    all_pos = all(difft > 0),
    min_difft = case_when(
      all_pos ~ min(difft),
      !all_pos ~ highest_negative(difft)
    ),
    myfilter = animal[difft == min_difft]
  ) %>%
  select(id, myfilter)  %>%
  ungroup()
```

returns:

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 2
     id myfilter
  <dbl> <chr>   
1     1 dog     
2     1 dog     
3     1 dog     
4     2 mouse   
5     2 mouse   
6     2 mouse
```